# Should I have dual monitors on the same graphics card or separate?

Tags: multiple-monitors, dual-gpu

Okay, I've got Win 10, two monitors and two gpus: Nvidia 1070 and 960 (and disabled on-board Intel something or other). I was running the 960 and was gifted the 1070, so I just tossed it in and put my main monitor on the 1070 (leaving my secondary on the 960). They are not physically linked but use the same driver.

I'm wondering if the 960 is really "doing" anything of use aside from using power, and if keeping the monitors on separate cards really matters.

I decided to look up whether or not there are any real benefits of leaving the 960 in, or having the monitors on separate cards. It seems that the cards should work together when I'm doing something more gpu-intensive, but it all seems to be just hearsay online posts. I also found this site (https://www.lifewire.com/multiple-graphics-cards-834088), but it just seems very vague.

I may just pull the 960 and check benchmarks before/after, but figured I'd try to find some info already out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no real benefit here in sticking them on different cards.

There's a *few* neat things you can do with the 960 (like using it for a [dedicated phy-x card](http://www.nvidia.com/object/physx_faq.html#q4), [dx 12 multi adaptor support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn933253(v=vs.85).aspx), or various gpgpu things) but chances are you are not using both cards to full capabilities. I have a pair of *4k* monitors on a 980TI. I only can game on one monitor in most instances (and that does push the card to the limit) and I could, in theory do dual monitor, non gaming tasks on a lesser card.

So, I'd not bother too much with the 960, and keeping the monitors on seperate cards *unless* you wanted to mess with dx12 multiple card support or dedicated phy-x

Comment: Thank you for the details. I was unaware of the 960 being able to do that, but as it is I am on spring break and just playing GR Wildlands, so I am utilizing dx12. But great to know, and I'll just leave it as-is.

Answer (score 1):

Both the GTX1070 as well as the GTX960 support DirectX 12, which means they can work together in games that support DX12. You can just leave them in place. However, check if your PSU can handle it, as it would be a problem if it can't handle the cards.

-Thijs365